# Postgres: ANY function does not work on varchar array

Tags: postgresql

I have a "product" table with a `varchar[]` column to keep excluded companies.

When I select the array for a specific product, I get it like this:

```
SELECT excluded_company_codes FROM product WHERE code = '123'
excluded_company_codes
----------
{'10'}
```

However, oddly enough, when I try to check if company code exists in the array with `ANY` function, it doesn't work:

```
SELECT '10'=ANY(product.excluded_company_codes) where code = '123'
?column?
----------
false
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string in the array contains two single quotes. If you want to find that, you have to

```
SELECT '''10''' = ANY(product.excluded_company_codes)
FROM product
WHERE code = '123';
```

If you want to avoid doubling the quotes, you can use dollar quoting: `$$'10'$$`.